# Force WebMatrix3 through Corporate Proxy Server

Tags: webmatrix

I am trying to connect to an Azure website using WebMatrix3.  I am in a corporate setting and would need to use our proxy server.  How do I set this up?  I added the appropriate settings to WebMatrix.exe.config but it still always tries to go direct.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit more info to this one, in the hopes it will hit somebody's radar.

I too have tried following instructions at http://forums.iis.net/t/1214402.aspx?WebMatrix+behind+proxy, and I ended up adding the following section within WebMatrix.exe.config

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="true" proxyaddress="http://[our proxy url:port]"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

This helped me to log on to my Visual Studio online account, but WebMatrix still fails to import my account details with the error:

> There was no endpoint listening at https://management.core.windows.net/subscriptions that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 157.55.195.251:443

Anyone able to successfully use WebMatrix from behind a proxy that requires authentication?